# Find the function for the size of a hospital's orders

Tags: calculus

"A hospital is trying to decide how often it needs to procure endoscopes for its operating rooms. On an annual basis, 1200 endoscopes are needed. The orders (which we assume are always for the same fixed quantity) are placed x times per year at equal intervals. This means (taking 1 week as a time unit) that if e.g. x=1 then an order is placed annually, if x=2 every 26 weeks, if x=52 per week, etc.

a. Find the function P(x) that expresses the size of each order (number of endoscopes) as a function of the order frequency x so that in 52 weeks the hospital has ordered a total of the desired 1200 endoscopes.

b. The purchase cost for each 1 endoscope is €300. Also, the hospital incurs administrative costs of €400 for each order, as well as costs related to the storage of the endoscopes, which are calculated at
S(x) =10000/x. on an annual basis. Write the function TC(x) that corresponds to the total annual cost (purchase+annual administrative order costs+annual storage costs) for the hospital".

I tried it several times and I reached the conclusion
for (a) that P(x) = 1200/x
and for question (b) that
TC(X) = 300*P(x)+400*P(x)+S(x)=300*1200/x + 400*1200/x + 10000/x

Is may way of thinking correct?

Please, I would appreciate for your guidance.

Comment: $1200/x$ is the *size* of each order, but to calculate the "annual administrative order costs" you need to multiply the *number* of orders by $400$.

Comment: Thank you very much! So for b it is 
TC(X) = 300P(x)+400P(x)+S(x)=3001200/x + 4001200/x + 10000/x  ?

Comment: That's the same thing you already had, and I already told you it was wrong, and told you what you had to do instead. You have multiplied the SIZE of each order by $400$, when you ought to multiply the NUMBER of orders by $400$.

Comment: Thank you very much!